# Car rental time series forecasting

Tags: modeling, time-series, demand-distribution, forecasting

I have the time series of car rentals/demand in a location. The time axis is every hour for 3 months. The y-axis is number of car rentals/demand.

[image]

I want to do prediction for future hours given this information. I would like to know the prediction models for this type of data.

I am not sure about the performance of ARIMA or other time series predicion models given low values of car rentals at each hour (close to zero). The maximum is only 5 car rentals.

What are the typical and high accuracy methods? It could be statistical or machine-learning based models.

Comment: If you have a trend (including a constant one) and cycles, [exponential smoothing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_smoothing) is worth a try.

Comment: Just looking at the graph, modelling as a Poisson random variable may be sufficient. 8 periods a day for ~90 days gives us 720 periods in the sample. So just guessing some Poisson values, we get `dpois(0:5,0.8)*720` equals `323.5168542 258.8134833 103.5253933  27.6067716   5.5213543   0.8834167`. The fit for predictions of 3/4/5 days are pretty close to your graph I believe by eye.

Comment: @Pcump_Ravenclaw : would you mind sharing your data ?

Comment: Are there zeros in your demand history?  Do you anticipate needing any of the intermittent demand techniques?

Comment: @AndyW thanks for your reply. I don't entirely understand what you mean by "
fit for predictions of 3/4/5 days are pretty close to your graph I believe by eye". I suppose that the numbers: "323.5168542 258.8134833 103.5253933  27.6067716   5.5213543   0.8834167" are the number of periods with 0,1,2,3,4& 5 cars over this entire 3 month time period?

Comment: Yep you got it. Substitute the mean for your data, and feed it into the Poisson PMF. Then the "fit" is how close the predicted PMF density is to your actual data.

Comment: Asked & answered also at CV:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/578213/car-rental-time-series-forecasting

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has already been answered at Cross Validated SE: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/578213/car-rental-time-series-forecasting.